# Как работать с localStorage

Tags: javascript, функции, localstorage, данные

Пытаюсь создать подобие чек-листа. Не могу разобраться с localstorage. Ответил на собственный вопрос(см.ниже). Но возникла проблема при перезагрузке страницы сохраненные данные невозможно отредактировать. Можно ли решить эту проблему? Или придется другим способом реализовать чек-лист?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Список дел</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Список дел</h2>
    <div class="main">
      <input id="add" type="text" placeholder="Введите описание вашего дела...">
      <button id="button_add">Добавить</button>
    </div>
    <hr><ul id="check_list"></ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
#deleteTask {
width: 18px;
height: 18px;
opacity: 0.3;
margin-left: 10px;
}

#deleteTask:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#deleteTask:before, #deleteTask:after {
position: absolute;
content: ' ';
height: 15px;
width: 2px;
background-color: #333;
}

#deleteTask:before {
transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#deleteTask:after {
transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.done span {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: gray;
}
```

```
let buttonAdd = document.getElementById('button_add');
let checklist = document.getElementById('check_list');
let add = document.getElementById('add');

buttonAdd.addEventListener('click', function(){

  if (add.value === ''){
    return alert('Ошибка: Пустая строка');
  }
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  let newTask = li.innerHTML =`
    <span id = 'newTask' data-elem = 'text'>` + add.value + `</span>
    <input id = 'checkTask' data-elem = 'checkbox' type = 'checkbox'>
    <span id = 'deleteTask' data-elem = 'remove'></span>`;
  add.value = '';
  checklist.appendChild(li);

  li.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.dataset.elem) {
      switch (event.target.dataset.elem) {
        case 'text':
          let span = event.target;
          let input = document.createElement('input');
          input.value = event.target.innerHTML;
          span.innerHTML = '';
          span.appendChild(input);
          input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
              span.innerHTML = this.value;
            };
          });
        break;
        case 'checkbox':
          li.classList.toggle('done');
        break;
        case 'remove':
          li.parentElement.removeChild(li);
          event.preventDefault();
        break;
      };
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: В localStorage хранятся только строки, поэтому нужны будут `JSON.stringify()`/`JSON.parse()`.

Comment: @Yaant Ну вот я сохранил например хотя бы введенное значение как его вывести?  let data = JSON.stringify(newTask);
  localStorage.setItem("myKey", data);

Comment: А, не обратил внимания, что `newTask` у Вас и так строка, тогда можно и без `stringify`. Получаете аналогично - `data = localStorage.getItem('myKey')`, и потом делаете с этим, что Вам заблагорассудится.

Answer (score 2):

Хотел добавить пару строчек, случайно получилось 150+ )

У каждой записи должен быть свой уникальный идентификатор. В таком случае все записи можно хранить в объекте:

```
{
  "0": { text: 'запись-1' },
  "1": { text: 'запись-2' },
  "8": { text: 'запись-8', checked: 1 },
}
```

Состояние `checked` тоже придется хранить, чтобы после обновления страницы вернуть все галочки на свои места. А т.к. в `localStorage` можно хранить только строки, для сохранения объектов необходимо использовать `JSON.stringify(obj)`, а для чтения - `JSON.parse(string)`

+ Вы и так использовали делегирование событий, но отдельно для каждого `<li>`. Заодно вынес обработчики на родительский `<ul>`: При добавлении / удалении записей не придется вешать новые обработчики.

---

Приставки `storage, item` намекают, что здесь напрашивается группирование в объекты или классы. Но пока обойдемся разбросанными функциями.

* Код рабочий, но localStorage не работает при запуске на этом сайте. Пробуйте  [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/7zbpwu0q/)

```js
const storage_KEY = 'check_list';

let storage_items = (function get_saved_data() {

  let items = localStorage.getItem(storage_KEY);
  
  try {
  
    let data = JSON.parse(items);
    
    if (!data) throw new Error('no data');
    
    if (typeof data != 'object') {
      throw new Error('Expected Object, but found: ' + data);
    }
    
    return data;
    // Если благополучно получилось прочесть JSON, в переменную storage_items
    // попадет этот объект.
   
  } catch(e) {
  
    console.log(e);
    return {}; // иначе, новый пустой {}
  }

})();

console.log('%cITEMS:', 'color: orange', storage_items);

// Любое действие со storage, выполняет операции в объекте storage_items,
// затем вызывает storage_update(), который записывает объект в localStorage

function storage_update() {
  //test_start
  // Временный блок, чтобы поймать ошибки во время написания,
  // если вдруг прилетит id-не число.
  if (Object.keys(storage_items).some(isNaN)) {
    console.error(storage_items);
    throw new Error('NaN!');
  }
  //test_end

  localStorage.setItem(storage_KEY, JSON.stringify(storage_items));
}

function storage_empty() {
  localStorage.setItem(storage_KEY, null);
}

/***/
function storage_add(item_id, item_text) {
  storage_items[item_id] = { text: item_text };
  storage_update();
}

function storage_remove(item_id) {
  delete storage_items[item_id];
  storage_update();
}

/***/
function storage_edit_item(item_id, new_text) {
  storage_items[item_id].text = new_text;
  storage_update();
}

function storage_check_item(item_id) {
  storage_items[item_id].checked = 1;
  storage_update();
}

function storage_uncheck_item(item_id) {
  delete storage_items[item_id].checked;
  storage_update();
}

function storage_max_id() {
  // Выдает максимальное число из всех ключей (id) объекта.
  // Нужен, чтобы id новых задач не пересекались со старыми.
  return Math.max(0, ...Object.keys(storage_items));
}


/*****/
// <заметка>
// id элементов <li> создаются в виде id="task-число",
// но во все функции storage должны передаваться в виде числа.

let checklist = document.getElementById('check_list');

(function _init_list_from_storage() {
  // * Список всех записей уже получен и сохранен в объект storage_items
  let html = '';

  for (let id in storage_items) {
    let obj = storage_items[id];
    html += item_html(obj.text, id, obj.checked);
  }  
  
  checklist.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
})();


checklist.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let dataset = e.target.dataset.elem;
  if (!dataset) return;

  switch (dataset) {
    case 'text'    : item_edit(e);        break;
    case 'checkbox': item_toggle_done(e); break;
    case 'remove'  : item_remove(e);      break;
  }
});

function item_edit(e) {
  // Здесь можно использовать contentEditable, не стал менять вашу реализацию
  
  let span = e.target;
  let input = document.createElement('input');
  input.value = span.textContent;
  
  span.textContent = '';
  span.appendChild(input);
  
  input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      span.textContent = this.value;
      
      let id = item_numeric_id(span.closest('li'));
      storage_edit_item(id, this.value)
    }
  });
}

function item_toggle_done(e) {
  let li = e.target.closest('li');
  li.classList.toggle('done');
  
  let id = item_numeric_id(li);
  (e.target.checked ? storage_check_item : storage_uncheck_item)(id);
  // см. «Тернарный оператор».
  // Здесь выбирается одна из функций в зависимости от условия,
  // которая затем вызывается с аргументом (id);
}

function item_remove(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  let li = e.target.closest('li');
  storage_remove(item_numeric_id(li));
  
  li.remove();
}

/***/
let add_btn = document.getElementById('button_add');
let add_inp = document.getElementById('add');

add_btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (add_inp.value === '') {
    return alert('Ошибка: Пустая строка');
  }

  item_add(add_inp.value);  
  add.value = '';
});

/***/
let unique_id = storage_max_id() + 1;

function item_numeric_id(li) {
  // "task-11" → 11
  return Number(li.id.match(/\d+/)[0]); // «Регулярные выражения»
}

function item_html(text, id, checked) {  
  return (`
    <li id="task-${ id }" class="${ checked ? 'done': '' }">
      <span data-elem="text">${ text }</span>
      <input data-elem="checkbox" type="checkbox" ${ checked ? 'checked' : '' }>
      <span class="delete" data-elem="remove"></span>
    </li>
  `);
}

function item_add(text) {
  let id = unique_id++;
  
  checklist.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', item_html(text, id));
  storage_add(id, text);
}
```

```css
.delete {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.delete:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.delete::before,
.delete::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  height: 15px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.delete::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.delete::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.done span {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Список дел</h2>
    <div class="main">
      <input id="add" type="text" placeholder="Введите описание вашего дела...">
      <button id="button_add">Добавить</button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <ul id="check_list"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: На мобиле не должно работать ?

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME Я пока магией на таком уровне не владею. Но спасибо за ответ. Ты фактически переписал код. Воот.. Можешь пожалуйста мой ответ посмотреть, можно ли этот вопрос немного проще решить или все же придется переписывать?

Comment: @MaximLensky Упс. Не знаю, тут ES6 ) [ здешний пример не запускается, сайт блокирует localStorage ]

Comment: @Joji Сделано. Не "с нуля", кстати, переписал. Куски вашего исходного варианта сохранены, немного в других местах и в другом виде :) * Добавлены комментарии.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал чтобы вам понять примерный принцип действия:

```
let buttonAdd = document.getElementById('button_add');
let checklist = document.getElementById('check_list');
let add = document.getElementById('add');
const tasks = localStorage.getItem('data') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')) : []
console.log(tasks)

tasks.forEach((item) => {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = item
  checklist.appendChild(li);
})

const saveTasks = () => {
  localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(tasks));
}

buttonAdd.addEventListener('click', function(){

  if (add.value === ''){
    return alert('Ошибка: Пустая строка');
  }
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  let newTask = li.innerHTML =`
    <span id = 'newTask' data-elem = 'text'>` + add.value + `</span>
    <input id = 'checkTask' data-elem = 'checkbox' type = 'checkbox'>
    <span id = 'deleteTask' data-elem = 'remove'></span>`;
  add.value = '';
  const taskId = tasks.push(newTask)
  saveTasks()
  checklist.appendChild(li);

  li.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.dataset.elem) {
      switch (event.target.dataset.elem) {
        case 'text':
          let span = event.target;
          let input = document.createElement('input');
          input.value = event.target.innerHTML;
          span.innerHTML = '';
          span.appendChild(input);
          input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
              span.innerHTML = this.value;
            };
          });
        break;
        case 'checkbox':
          li.classList.toggle('done');
        break;
        case 'remove':
            tasks.splice(newTask, 1)
            saveTasks()
          li.parentElement.removeChild(li);
          event.preventDefault();
        break;
      };
    };
  });
});
```

Хотя по-хорошему тут надо весь код переписывать. В частности список должен быть сделан в виде массива объектов, а при добавлении в массив и удалении - список нужно перерисовывать.

Comment: Получается реализация чек-листа таким способом плохой вариант? И ответ, что я написал ниже нельзя решить?

Answer (score 0):

Собственно получилось сохранить. Но при перезагрузке страницы. Редактирование сохраненной строки не представляется возможным. Можно ли это исправить?

```
let buttonAdd = document.getElementById('button_add');
let checklist = document.getElementById('check_list');
let add = document.getElementById('add');

let todo;
function toLocal(){
  todo = checklist.innerHTML;
  localStorage.setItem('todo', todo);
}
buttonAdd.addEventListener('click', function newElem(){

  if (add.value === ''){
    return alert('Ошибка: Пустая строка');
  }
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  let newTask = li.innerHTML =`
    <span id = 'newTask' data-elem = 'text'>` + add.value + `</span>
    <input id = 'checkTask' data-elem = 'checkbox' type = 'checkbox'>
    <span id = 'deleteTask' data-elem = 'remove'></span>`;
  add.value = '';
  checklist.appendChild(li);
  li.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.dataset.elem) {
      switch (event.target.dataset.elem) {
        case 'text':
          let span = event.target;
          let input = document.createElement('input');
          input.value = event.target.innerHTML;
          span.innerHTML = '';
          span.appendChild(input);
          input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
              span.innerHTML = this.value;
            };
          });
        toLocal();
        break;
        case 'checkbox':
          li.classList.toggle('done');
        toLocal();
        break;
        case 'remove':
          li.parentElement.removeChild(li);
          event.preventDefault();
        toLocal();
        break;
      };
    };
  });
});

if(localStorage.getItem('todo')) {
  checklist.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("todo");
};
```

Comment: `li.addEventListener('click'` — вот это, надо вынести из обработчика клика и повесить отдельно на `<ul>` — `checklist.addEve...` вместо `li`. Тогда не придется для каждого li добавлять свой обработчик. А внутри обработчика добавить `let li = e.target.closest('li')` — находит ближайший элемент `li`, внутри которого находится кликнутый блок. А для `case: 'text'` нужно перенести `toLocal();` внутри `if (e.keyCode...`, чтобы сохранялось после редактирования. Других ошибок вроде нет. Кроме того, что всё слишком "в кучу") Вам потом придется заново вникать в весь код, для внесения любых изменений.

Comment: Ну и, хранение всего HTML целиком в localStorage - не лучшая идея. Я специально собрал только необходимые данные в объект (текст и состояние чекбокса), чтобы поменьше памяти занять) `id = 'newTask'` — кстати, в HTML не допускается повторение нескольких одинаковых id (одиночные кавычки, строго говоря, тоже). В таком случае, можно заменить их на class.